# Reverse y axis in a plot generated with SciDraw

Tags: scidraw

In Mathematica, `ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse"` can do this job. I am wondering if SciDraw has an easy way to achieve the same thing. I have read the manual, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - "SciDraw is a system for preparing publication-quality scientific figures with Mathematica." I believe that there are many questions related to extensions of Mathematica whether by Wolfram or a third party.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, `YPlotRange` can do this job. For example, `YPlotRange->{-2,2}` and `YPlotRange->{2,-2}`.